# Ошибка при подключении OCI8 в OpenServer

Tags: php

Есть необходимость подключить OCI8 в OpenServer
PHP 8.1TS 64x, OCI8_19 пробовал x86, x64 TS и соответствующие разрядности библиотеки Instant Client.
Пробовал переместить .dll Instant Client в ext и apache/bin.
Добавил Instant Client в PATH.
Поставил все версии VC++
Проблема осталось той же...

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_19' (tried: c:/dev/ospanel/modules/php/PHP_8.1/ext\oci8_19 (Не найден указанный модуль), c:/dev/ospanel/modules/php/PHP_8.1/ext\php_oci8_19.dll (%1 не является приложением Win32)) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: А пробовал после размещения в ext, включать в настройках?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге проблема была в неверно установленном Instant Client.
Установил не ту разрядность и версию.